# How to delete files off USB using Python

Tags: python, usb

Trying this method to remove files on a usb but wont work. What is the best approach to remove files off a usb in python. shutil.rmtree() I dont want as that removes folder as well as all files.

```
import os
import glob

os.system('mount /dev/sdb1 /media/sdb')

usb_files = glob.glob('/media/sdb/*')
for f in usb_files:
    os.remove(f)
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No compiles ok but no files were deleted in /media/sdb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is almost certainly happening is your `os.system` call either does not succeed or your glob matches nothing so there is nothing to iterate over, you should be using `subprocess.check_call` which will raise a CalledProcessError if the call returns a non-zero exit status:

```
from subprocess import check_call
check_call(['mount', '/dev/sdb1','/media/sdb'])

usb_files = glob.glob('/media/sdb/*')
for f in usb_files:
    os.remove(f)
```

You should add a `print(usb_files)`  to debug, it is certainly empty in your own code and it is good to verify what you match regardless.

`glob` does not care if you path actually exists so if nothing gets mounted glob won't complain:

```
In [3]: print(glob.glob('/gobbledegook'))
[]
```

And os.system might output a string if it fails but it won't raise an error:

```
In [5]: os.system("mount /dev/sdb1 /goobledegook")
mount: only root can do that
```

You could check if the system call returned `0` but using subprocess in general is the preferable approach.

Comment: print(usb_files) is not printing anyting to the screen. However if I just manually mount into the usb and "ls", the files are there. So the usb is not empty

Comment: Yes done exactly as you said did not return any error

Comment: try, `check_call(["ls", '/media/sdb'])` and see if that outputs anything and `os.listdir('/media/sdb')`

Comment: No sorry my mistake it is working now didn't realize i was doing an unmount in the script, before i was deleting contents of the USB. Very stupid. Thank you once again

Comment: @homeGrown, no worries.

Comment: That's why it is important to post your full and exact code when you are having trouble.